# How does botframework v4 end conversation?

Tags: botframework

How can I trigger to end chat session using Microsoft bot framework version 4?

I implemented a bot with a timeout timer to detect user inactivity.  If there is no user interaction for more than X minutes, the bot will "timeout", end the chat session and force the user to start over.  In v3 bot framework, this can be easily done with session.endChat.  How can I do the same in version 4?  All the readings recommend cancelAllDialogs or cancelAllDialogsAsync, but all this does is to clear the stack.  The session is still active with the same conversation id.  Thanks in advance for any help in this regard.